# Does shortcut with radio's wire harness 12v constant (Yellow) and the red (accesorry 12v) could have damaged car components?

Tags: chevrolet, audio, aveo

Here is the diagram of Factory radio wiring ...  I burned a 10 a fuse linking the radio itself and the Clock. But i didnt removed the battery doing the job si thats why i have shortcut .... Yeah it was stupid. Want to know if damage could have happened to ecm, ecu or anything else ... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always a chance that something got damaged when the fuses blow, however chances in this case are minuscule. 
Make sure the situation with the short circuit is resolved, replace the fuse and don't do any work, especially electrical, with the power source connected.

Comment: Alirigh thanks for the answer. Well gm told me if the check engine isnt on, There is nothing to the ecu. Also the Factory diagram show the concerned fuse and would mean the over volt or over amp would have stoped at the fuse.

Comment: Normally the ecu is protected itself by fuses right ?